# jQuery click function not working even after using document.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm Trying to popup an alert when a button is clicked using jQuery but for some reason its not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#find").click(function () {
        alert("Hi");
    });
});
```

Here is the link to code:[Weather](https://jsfiddle.net/ko6k0nxu/)

Kindly let me what I'm I doing wrong.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Please, post your code here, and add the jsFiddle link only for reference. Also, in your question there is no jsFiddle at all.

Comment: you didnt include the script.please include the script it will work

Comment: @LeoFarmer  The code has been posted

Comment: @madistack You're not referencing `jQuery`, so it will not work. I've [edited your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ko6k0nxu/1/) to include it, and it's working.

Comment: please check again with the update

Comment: @Buzinas I have included the jquery in my actual code but it still doesn't work. <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: because you dont have the button to click i added that on the update please checl

Comment: @all I found what I'm doing wrong I probably shouldn't have used the minified link. I used the normal one

Comment: @Pekka thanks got it

Answer (score -1):

You should try this instead.

```
$(function(){
$("#find").on('click',function () {
        alert("Hi");
    });
});
```